# How to get browser currently open pages?

Tags: android, browser

Tha question is simple:

How to get browser currently opened pages?

Some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to [git the browser code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser.git) and see if there's a way.  The browser is not part of the OS but a replaceable app provided by the AOSP as default.